# ConcurrentModificationException Room Android

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am using Room in my app and while inserting data into my db a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown at times. Why is it so?

I use a pagination api and after each api call I insert dataList into my db using

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                    
                    appDatabase.dataDao().insertMultipleData(dataList);                    
            }
        }).start();
```

where

```
appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
```

**Insert operation**

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertMultipleData(List<Data> dataList);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical scenario if you are trying to insert data in a paginated list. Since you have not pasted error logs, i assume that the error is caused on the dataList object. In that case the error message woule look like below.

```
 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
        at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insertAndReturnIdsArray(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:131)
        at com.myApp.data.database.entities.FeedDataDao_Impl.insertAll(FeedDataDao_Impl.java:220)
```

If this is the case, the error is caused by paralell modification of same variable by different threads. In this case i assume that you are inserting the data to database and at the same doing new service call(pagination) to fetch data updating the same data object. Or this can be thrown even if you remove the contents from original array source while it is being inserted. The solution is pretty simple. You can copy the variable *dataList* to a new variable and use the new local variable as parameter to your insert call.

Eg:  (Kotlin)

```
val localCopy = dataList
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).feedDataDao().insertAll(localCopy).size

 }.invokeOnCompletion {
        Log.d("Inserted all items")
 }
```

Eg:  (Java)

```
List<MyDataType> localCopy = dataList       
AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).feedDataDao().insertAll(localCopy).size
```

Comment: Mine is same problem but this solution not working for me. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68082863/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-at-java-util-arraylistitr-next

Comment: well explained, Thank you! in my case I was removing the data and loading it same time!!