# java.util.concurrentmodificationexception at java.util.arraylist$itr.next

Tags: java, android, loops, iterator

I am getting data from firebase real time database and while iterating over datasnapshot i get `java.util.concurrentmodificationexception at java.util.arraylist$itr.next` error at line number at line number 493 when insert data into room database like this.

`Inventory.getInstance(Inventory.this.getActivity(), 1).InventoryDAO().InsertData(items);`

This is the whole method where i am getting this error.

```
private List<InventoryEntity_TableColums> message; // Class Variable


      private synchronized void append_inventory_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
    
    
    
        String inventory_Msg, inventory_TO, inventory_FROM, inventory_TimeStamp, inventory_FCM_FROM, inventory_FCM_TO, inventory_Type, Random_ID, inventory_FROM_ID, inventory_Receiver_ID;
    
    
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            inventory_Msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            inventory_FROM = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            inventory_FROM_ID = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            inventory_TO = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            inventory_TimeStamp = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            inventory_Type = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Random_ID = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            inventory_FCM_FROM = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            inventory_FCM_TO = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
    
    
            // return count of RANDOM ID  in room
            int hasValue = inventoryRoomDatabase.getInstance(getActivity(), 1).inventoryDAO().CheckValueExist(Random_ID);
            Log.d(TAG, "Has inventory " + hasValue);
    
            if (hasValue == 0) {
                inventoryEntity_TableColums inventoryEntity_tableColums;
                if (inventory_Type.equals("1")) {
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums(Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,  "1");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
                   
    
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("2")) {
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums(Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg, "2");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
                   
    
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("3")) {
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums(Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg, "3");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
                    
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("4")) { //THIS IS FOR SEARCHED IMAGES NOT FOR GIF IMAGES
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums( Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"4");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
    
                   
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("5")) {
                    //Adding inventory Data Into Database
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums( Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"5");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
    
                   
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("6")) {
                    //Adding inventory Data Into Database
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums( Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"6");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
    
                  
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("7")) {
                    //Adding inventory Data Into Database
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums(Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"7");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
                   
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("8")) {
                    //Adding inventory Data Into Database
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums( Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"8");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
    
                 
    
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("9")) {
                    //Adding inventory Data Into Database
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums(Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"9");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
    
                    
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("10")) {
                    //Adding inventory Data Into Database
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums( Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"10");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
                  
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("11")) {
                    //Adding inventory Data Into Database
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums( Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"11");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
    
                  
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("12")) {
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums( Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"12");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Message" + inventory_Msg);
    
                 
                } else if (inventory_Type.equals("13")) {
                    inventoryEntity_tableColums = new inventoryEntity_TableColums( Session.getUserID(),inventory_Msg,"13");
                    message.add(inventoryEntity_tableColums);
    
                    
    
                }
    
            }
    
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
//THIS LINE WHERE I AM GETTING java.util.concurrentmodificationexception at java.util.arraylist$itr.next at insertInventory
                inventoryRoomDatabase.getInstance(inventoryScreen.this.getActivity(), 1).inventoryDAO().Insertinventory(message);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Room Database's InsertInventroy

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void Insertinventory(List<InventoryEntity_TableColums> inv);
```

Comment: How does your method "insertInventory" looks like?

Comment: @Nemanja Please Check updated question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in the `insertinventory` method you use an iterator to iterate over list and you want to add new elements to the list. The problem is that you can't use the same iterator for a modified list.

Comment: It's just a room database insert entry. Not using same iterator, i also posted `Insert` query for you to see if that method causes the issue

Comment: @Ritu Maybe this can be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737280/concurrentmodificationexception-room-android

Comment: Thanks for the help but i already tried link you posted.